# Modifying \section{} to make it colorful with LaTeX

Tags: latex

How can I change the \section{} style? Especially I want to change the color of section heading.

I happen to find some neat style following Edward R. Tufte (http://code.google.com/p/tufte-latex/), and I'm trying to find a way to modify the section color.

#### Added

color package works fine, but the thing is that the color chapter number is not changed.

```
\section{\color{Red}ELPA}
```

Comment: Same question on TeX.SE: [sectioning - Giving headlines a background color spanning across the entire typearea - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40034/giving-headlines-a-background-color-spanning-across-the-entire-typearea) || [color - Change Colour on Chapter/Section headings {Lyx} - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75667/change-colour-on-chapter-section-headings-lyx)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use package [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/).

Put this in the LaTeX header (before `\begin{document}`)

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{color}


\titleformat{\section}
{\color{red}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\color{red}\thesection}{1em}{}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
%\allsectionsfont{\color{blue}\itshape\underline}
\sectionfont{\color{blue}\itshape\selectfont}
\subsectionfont{\color{green}\itshape\selectfont}
```

I could change color using sectsty style.

Comment: For some other reason this was the package and lines of code that stopped driving me nuts first. :) (I needed simply `\sectionfont{\color{red}}`.)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the [`color` package](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors)?

```
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}

\section{\color{Red} Section Header}
```

You can also define your own colors:

```
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\definecolor{MetallicGold}{RGB}{212, 175, 55}

\section{\color{MetallicGold} Section Header}
```

You can define a command to make it simplier to type:

```
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\definecolor{MetallicGold}{RGB}{212, 175, 55}
\newcommand{\coloredsection}[2]{\section{\color{#1} #2} }

\coloredsection{MetallicGold}{Section Header}
```

Comment: @In silico : It seems to work, but the section number is not changed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the titlesec package and its \titleformat command.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to only change the format of the section number (and subsection and subsubsection), while leaving the section title as normal, then you can do it like this, with the `titlesec` package

```tex
\usepackage{titlesec}
%modifies the format of section,subsection,subsubsection
\titlelabel{\textcolor{red}\thetitle\quad}
```